# Check text and add multiple worksheets columns

Tags: excel

I need to check if the text of the worksheet is the same as the one of another cell, and if it is equal, it adds the values of a column next to it. But, I have about 20 spreadsheets in the file, I need this check in each worksheet.

[image]

`=SOMASE('11'!I4:I200;A2;'11'!G4:G200)`

My function I can just check this in a column, I need in this function cell to be checked and summed the values of all the columns

Comment: This is the problem when entering data into different sheets. lt's hard to consolidate for reporting across all data. A better approach would be to have data all in ONE sheet, add a column for the date (or whatever the tab numbers signify. To me they look like days of a date stamp). The you can have a separate sheet to report on the data for one day or all days or however you want . Or you could easily create a pivot table with slicers for dates and categories.

Comment: Even consider the data in a separate file, perhaps CSV, and a separate summary workbook.

Comment: Clarification request : .. 1. where does this : ".. the text of the worksheet" refers to? | 2. the formula you had shown... 2a) in which cell does it applies.. & 2b) since we cannot see the column label in the attached picture.. It was not really clear which data does the `sumif()` function work on..